# AWS EC2 response not received on the client side

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am using a t2.micro instance to serve requests to a front-end hosted on S3. Interestingly enough, 90% of my users can get a response. However, there are 10% who just can't get any response back. Some of these users are in an enterprise environment.

I had the chance to check one of my friend's Chrome dev tool (using on our front-end) and saw a weird behaviour where no response was sent back. Then, I sent a get json request to the endpoint directly. From there onwards, everything started to work. Recently, a potential early adopter from an enterprise tried our prototype and same thing happened again. This time, I wasn't so lucky and got a good lecturing from the user. :(

I tried searching online for tons of possibility. I can only come up with 2:
( i ) Some firewall blocks response sending back from EC2 addresses (I am not using Route 51 yet to attach our domain name yet)
( ii ) There is some sort of routing issues going on

If you think that these are good reasons for what's happening, please let me know what can I do to fix them. Otherwise, what are the debugging steps that I can take?

You can find our site here:
http://resohub.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
and test if you have the same problem.

**UPDATES:**

(a) Typo in t1.micro. I am using t2.micro.

(b) I have a very low request/sec.

(c) I know this isn't an application problem for 2 reasons. One, I always use my own web app on a daily basis. It had never given me any issues. Two, I have server logs and I do not see any errors at all. Nonetheless, I am going to add more logging messages just in case.

(d) I know that once a user cannot received an response from the server at time t, it will not be able to receive any response from there onwards. Just to emphasize, in 1 case, I was able solve this issue by asking my friend to make direct request to the endpoint.

(e) I eat my own dog food every day. I have seen it being slow but not the case where my users tell me that the results are never being returned. The problem that 10% of the user face is results are never being returned.

Comment: Unless you are receiving a lot of traffic (are you?), then it's highly unlikely that the fact you are using t1.micro is relevant. You can always stop and then restart on a different instance type to test if you like. You need to spend some time debugging one of these failure scenarios. Is the client request actually reaching your web server?

Comment: My site is certainly not getting a lot of traffic... And I have logs and I can certainly see that the requests arrived at my server. I am pretty they were sent off properly too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the requests eventually (in the server logs)? Do you have logs server side?

having to guess I would tell you to look at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html

section about CPU credits. A hunch at this point but: if you don't use it for a while it works just fine. If you start putting it under heavy load you will start experiencing this.

Comment: It's a `t1.micro` according to the question... which is similar to t2 except that the throttling mechanism isn't exposed and the performance degrades not at all gracefully after just a few seconds of heavy CPU instead of a few hours.  Still, I suspect you are on to something.  Not sure why anybody would stick with the t1 instance class.

Comment: I am sorry. It is a t2.micro. A typo in my question. @Mircea, I have my server logs and I can definitely see the request is processed properly. On my own network, I have never been able to reproduce this which is really driving me nuts.

Comment: the way to reproduce this is to hit the machine with a lot of traffic at once. you can use something like apache bench: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench what you're looking for is how much time is the client hanging around waiting for the response, vs the how much time it takes on the server. hope this helps.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the reason to stick with the instance is usually cost (it's either in the free tier or super cheap)

Comment: @Mircea that is only true of t2.  My point was about t1, which is not as cheap as t2, and is much more prone to overload than t2.  As OP had this information incorrect, the point is somewhat moot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no worries. I've misread the t1.micro as t2.micro when answering initially.

Comment: actually I did :) the OP corrected it after :) so you were right initially :)

Comment: @Mircea - Thanks for pointing me to ApacheBench. I used Gatling before and I would give it a try some time. But, I don't think that is the issue. For now, I think what I will do is go to some place where this issue is known to occur and check exactly what is wrong.